# Changing the default product limit for Magento's "New Products" module

Tags: magento

As I understand, by default, Magento's "New Products" module (new.phtml) display the last 8 products listed. How is it possible to change the default and possibly even remove the limit altogether (yes, that would totally change the behavior of the "New Products" module, I understand)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the "New Products block" (`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`) has the `setProductsCount($count)` method. You can set the number you want.

If you add this block via layout, you can set $count like this

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" .....>
...
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>100</count></action>
...
</block>
```

This number will be used as a "PageSize filter" in the `_getProductCollection()` function.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to add the Toolbar and set limit to Pager as mentioned [here](http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/) , or use setProductsCount($count) on product collection

2nd may be to override the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` and remove `->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount()) ->setCurPage(1)` from `_getProductCollection()`